# How to "reindex" with Dask DataFrame

Tags: dask

I'm looking into using dask for time-series research with large volumes of data.  One common operation that I use is realignment of data to a different index (the reindex operation on pandas dataframe's).  I noticed that the reindex function is not currently supported in the dask dataframe API, but is in the DataArray API.  Are there plans to add this function?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could use the `Dataframe.set_index()` method combined with `.resample()` for that same purpose.

Comment: Would work for evenly sampled data, but sometimes the new index we want may be arbitrary.